# Unspecified error trying to install .NET 4.5.2 Developer Pack

Tags: installation, .net-4.5.2

I downloaded the [.NET 4.5.2 Developer Pack](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=328857) and have since been struggling to install it on one particular 64-bit Windows 7 machine so that I can use it with Visual Studio 2013, which was successfully installed. (Worked just fine on all other machines I've installed the framework on)

It fails right near the end of the first extraction phase with a "An error was encountered. Unspecified error" and immediately deletes all the files it just extracted. I've been looking for an error log or any sort of indication of what's caused the problem - can't fine a trace of anything.

Any ideas on what I can do to get it to install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved that issue in the next way:
1) Extract installer as archive(just with WinRAR using mouse right button click - extract)
2) Run Setup.exe

If you get "Fatal error" on install - reboot the system. Some programs or previous actions can brake installation

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I did just that and it worked like a breeze.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I tried this, but I don't see Setup.exe inside the extracted files?

Comment: When you extracted the files, did it decompress to about 5.3 GB? The Setup.exe should be easy to spot. Oh and you'll also need about 8 GB of space to successfully install it I found.

Comment: @Ceka you just save me from frustration! Bless you!

Answer (score 14):

My co-worker pointed at something that helped me. It's hard to believe but when all the files get extracted from this 350 Mb setup files they take up about 6 Gb! I had only about 4.5 Gb free on my hard drive and after some cleanup the SDK installed with no problem.

Comment: I believe this was the root of my install issue as well.  Might have been nice to have a "you don't have enough disk space" error.  Sigh.